# How to filter javasciptarray based on a filter object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter

Based on the filter object, I need to filter out the data. Below is the filter object and sample data with required output. The filter object is generated dynamically via a multi search component from ui. Then when the user hits search the data needs to be filtered.

```
var filter = {
  city: 'pana',
  hospname: 'sara'
};
var data = [
  {
    "city": "Hot Springs",
    "hospname": "St. Vincent Hot Springs",
    "version": "VA48A",
    "sysid1": "CT67400",
    "type": "CompressedFile",
    "rowIndex": 0,
    "selected": false,
    "disabled": true
  },
  {
    "city": "Panama City",
    "hospname": "Bay Medical Center",
    "version": "VA48A",
    "sysid1": "CT67399",
    "type": "CompressedFile",
    "rowIndex": 1,
    "selected": false,
    "disabled": true
  },
  {
    "city": "Sarasota",
    "hospname": "Sarasota Memorial Hospital",
    "version": "VA44A",
    "sysid1": "C7393",
    "type": "CompressedFile",
    "rowIndex": 2,
    "selected": false,
    "disabled": true
  },
  {
    "city": "DAVENPORT",
    "hospname": "Genesis Medical Center",
    "version": "VA48A",
    "sysid1": "C6333",
    "type": "CompressedFile",
    "rowIndex": 6,
    "selected": false,
    "disabled": true
  }
];
```

Expected output:

```
[{
    "city": "Panama City",
    "hospname": "Bay Medical Center",
    "version": "VA48A",
    "sysid1": "CT67399",
    "type": "CompressedFile",
    "rowIndex": 1,
    "selected": false,
    "disabled": true
  },
  {
    "city": "Sarasota",
    "hospname": "Sarasota Memorial Hospital",
    "version": "VA44A",
    "sysid1": "CT67393",
    "type": "CompressedFile",
    "rowIndex": 2,
    "selected": false,
    "disabled": true
  }]
```

Comment: Try writing a function for it.

Comment: @KooiInc well, I am trying that out and not able to arrive at a solution.  The below function only works for single value in filter object.
data.filter(function(item) {
  for (var key in filter) {
  if (item[key].toLowerCase().indexOf(filter[key].toLowerCase()) == -1){
    return false;
   }
  }
  return true;
  
});

Comment: Well, why didn't you include that in your question then? That would've given more clues for someone to answer it. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may be informative about how to ask a good question. [Or this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I agree. I will improve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started on a more generic version where you can add attributes on the filter object.

```js
var filter = {
  city: 'pana',
  hospname: 'sara'
};
var data = [
  {
    "city": "Hot Springs",
    "hospname": "St. Vincent Hot Springs",
    "version": "VA48A",
    "sysid1": "CT67400",
    "type": "CompressedFile",
    "rowIndex": 0,
    "selected": false,
    "disabled": true
  },
  {
    "city": "Panama City",
    "hospname": "Bay Medical Center",
    "version": "VA48A",
    "sysid1": "CT67399",
    "type": "CompressedFile",
    "rowIndex": 1,
    "selected": false,
    "disabled": true
  },
  {
    "city": "Sarasota",
    "hospname": "Sarasota Memorial Hospital",
    "version": "VA44A",
    "sysid1": "C7393",
    "type": "CompressedFile",
    "rowIndex": 2,
    "selected": false,
    "disabled": true
  },
  {
    "city": "DAVENPORT",
    "hospname": "Genesis Medical Center",
    "version": "VA48A",
    "sysid1": "C6333",
    "type": "CompressedFile",
    "rowIndex": 6,
    "selected": false,
    "disabled": true
  }
];

let results;

if (Object.keys(filter).length === 0)
  results = data;
else {
  results = data.filter((item) => {
      return Object.keys(filter).find(key => {
          return item[key] && item[key].toLowerCase().includes(filter[key].toLowerCase());
      });
  });  
}

console.log(results);
```

Comment: This doesn't work when the filter object is empty. If the filter object is empty it must return all the data.

Comment: Then you just to add a if statement and check whether `filter` has attributes or not. I have updated my answer.

Comment: @Nishanth Don't forget to accept my answer and upvote if it solves your problem so that I can release some Oxytocin.

Comment: @marcos Done Buddy

Answer (score 1):

```js
var filter = {
  city: 'pana',
  hospname: 'sara'
};
var data = [
  {
    "city": "Hot Springs",
    "hospname": "St. Vincent Hot Springs",
    "version": "VA48A",
    "sysid1": "CT67400",
    "type": "CompressedFile",
    "rowIndex": 0,
    "selected": false,
    "disabled": true
  },
  {
    "city": "Panama City",
    "hospname": "Bay Medical Center",
    "version": "VA48A",
    "sysid1": "CT67399",
    "type": "CompressedFile",
    "rowIndex": 1,
    "selected": false,
    "disabled": true
  },
  {
    "city": "Sarasota",
    "hospname": "Sarasota Memorial Hospital",
    "version": "VA44A",
    "sysid1": "C7393",
    "type": "CompressedFile",
    "rowIndex": 2,
    "selected": false,
    "disabled": true
  },
  {
    "city": "DAVENPORT",
    "hospname": "Genesis Medical Center",
    "version": "VA48A",
    "sysid1": "C6333",
    "type": "CompressedFile",
    "rowIndex": 6,
    "selected": false,
    "disabled": true
  }
];

const result=data.filter(item=>item.city.toLowerCase().includes(filter.city.toLowerCase()) || item.hospname.toLowerCase().includes(filter.hospname.toLowerCase()) )

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Can it be dynamic instead of hard coding values of the filter object ?

Comment: its not hard coded..i have utilised `filter` variable.

Comment: you can change the variable name as per your use case.

Comment: I know, But he filter object may have zero or more values at any given time. hence

Answer (score 1):

In ES6 you can do it like this

```
var results = data.filter(function(item)=>{
   return item.city === filter.city || item.hospname === filter.hospname;
});
```

Happy coding!

Comment: The filter object may have no value or one or more value. Hence he solution needs to be dynamic.